# Is it correct to say: "(drink) was getting to him/her?"

Tags: sentence

I'm pretty sure you can say this:

> I wondered if the **alcohol** was getting to her.

But I'm not very sure about this:

> I wondered if the **wine** was getting to her, but I could tell she
>   wasn't drunk yet.

Would people normally say something like that? If not, how to say it in a more natural way?

Comment: In what way do you think is *wine* different from *alcohol* in the context? Does *wine* seem unqualified to you to "get to something"?

Comment: @Kris Well, maybe I'm mistaken, but I read the sentence like this: "The wine was getting to her *brain*." It's the alcohol that gets there, not the wine. Maybe I'm thinking too much.

Comment: Then it's not much to do with language or grammar, as you realize.

Comment: The edit from "into" to "to" changes the question so much that the current answers do not fit it anymore.

Comment: @MετάEd: I just re-edited the question so that it says "getting into her" instead of "getting to her". Now it doesn't have to be closed. Both answers were downvoted once because they refer to "getting into". That seems to me to be a valuable mistake: it's not idiomatic, so users may learn something from seeing how the idiomatic and non-idiomatic differ. I would have rejected the previous edit as making too radical a change in the OP's question, even though the OP himself committed the edit (without understanding its effect).

Comment: Sure it's possible; [have a look](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alcohol+was+getting+to%2Cwine+was+getting+to&year_start=1965&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: @MετάEd It was clear all along that the question was **not** about *to/into*, but about *alcohol/wine*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you’re talking about some sort of IV drip-line, the normal phrasing is that it was **getting *to*** her, not that it was getting “into”.

> I wondered if the alcohol was **getting to** her.
>
> I wondered if the wine was **getting to** her, but I could tell she wasn't drunk yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really say "I wondered whether the {alcohol / wine} was getting into her" unless you mean that you don't know whether she was drinking it or whether the intravenous connection between her vein and the bottle with the {alcohol / wine} was delivering the product.

I think what you want to say is "I wondered whether the {alcohol / wine} **was getting to her**", which means you wondered whether she was being affected by the alcohol, i.e. getting drunk.